# Local device DNS thinks I am in the wrong country

Tags: ubuntu, networking, dns, networkmanager, dnsmasq

I recently traveled to Canada, and once I arrived my Ubuntu 16.10 laptop started having DNS resolution issues after a couple days when it became confused about what country I was in. Initially I could fix this by flushing my DNS in Chrome, but quickly realized that the issue was with my local device.

I have been back in the U.S. for over a month and my laptop remains confused about what country I am in. Eventually, my network access to websites, package repos, or anything else, becomes blocked due to DNS resolution errors. When I visit Youtube (for example), it always has a "Youtube CA" logo in the upper left.

I can temporarily fix this problem by doing:

```
sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
sudo systemctl restart dns-clean
sudo systemctl restart pppd-dns
```

However, after anywhere between five minutes to two hours the DNS resolution problems return. I then have to restart services again to fix DNS resolution errors and regain access to websites. It may be interesting to note that some websites become unresolved due to DNS whereas others are still accessible, and it seems random to me which fall in each category.

My `resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

My `/run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf` looks like:

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

To answer the questions below, I am connected to the internet via a wired router with Automatic DHCP. However, this problem also occured with multiple WiFi connections I have used since returning from Canada. Both automatic DNS and manual DNS with `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` cause this problem.

Provider seems to be (using `traceroute` as requested):

```
5  be-7725-cr02.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.93.125)  12.183 ms  12.324 ms  12.291 ms
6  hu-0-12-0-7-pe01.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.89.22)  12.114 ms  9.928 ms  9.847 ms
7  as15169-pe01.56marietta.ga.ibone.comcast.net (75.149.228.170)  35.742 ms  36.479 ms  36.491 ms
```

I tried the suggestion below of adding `prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;` to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, restarting the device, and flushing the DNS in Chrome, and I am still unable to access websites due to DNS resolution issues.

Just to be clear on what I mean by DNS resolution issues, the error I am receiving is:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> www.example.com’s server DNS address could not be found.
>
> Try:
>
> Checking the proxy, firewall, and DNS configuration
>
> DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG

Comment: 127.* is your machine.

Comment: @choroba Yes I know. That is why I am fixing this by restarting my device's DNS and not blaming Google's DNS.

Comment: Geolocation by Youtube etc. works by checking your public IP. That has nothing to do with DNS, or "what country your local device thinks it's in". On top of that, you are running some misconfigured local DNS cache (IPs `127.0.1.1` and `127.0.0.53` are not what you'd normally use for localhost), and I'm not sure why you use `dnsmask` as a cache (you probably don't need a local DHCP server). How do you connect to the internet (VPN?), and what provider does is your public IP belong to (use `traceroute` etc. on e.g. `youtube.com`).

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the info. 127.0.1.1 was the default for the packages installed with Ubuntu 16.10. 127.0.0.53 comes from a plugin called `landrush` that I have installed for software called `vagrant`. It starts up a mini-DNS server on my local device for virtual instances to network with each other. It is the default IP for that. I can answer the questions in an edit.

Comment: I really doubt the 5th hop is what shows up as your public IP (for me it's the 3rd hop). Please do include the other hops, or verify for yourself that they can't be mistaken as Canadian IPs. Anyway, `68.86.93.125` is Comcast and should show up as in the US for any reasonable geolocation. I've no idea why youtube would mistake it, but it's a problem on their end, and not on yours. Let me repeat, DNS got nothing to do with. And your reverse DNS lookup seems to be working fine, so DNS can't be completely broken.

Comment: @dirkt It is definitely possible for the problem to be due to DNS. If Matt is getting a Canadian server's IP address rather than a US IP address when resolving `youtube.com`, that might cause him to get Canadian Youtube content rather than US Youtube content. It depends how Youtube identifies clients. AFAIK Youtube does not use this for content restrictions (it would be too easy to defeat) but it might explain the logo.

Comment: It does not.  The country for the logo is taken from YouTube user account preferences, and is stored in a cookie named `PREF`.

Comment: @dirkt Ok so if the fact that this began to occur shortly into my trip to a foreign country is a red herring/coincidence, there is still the fact that I am having DNS resolution errors that build up over time and then disappear once I restart DNS services. However, these comments have led me to believe that maybe the problem here is that my laptop is using the mini-DNS server that landrush set up and that is causing the issues.

Comment: You are using at least two DNS services (landrush + dnsmasq), and of course this is asking for trouble, unless you made sure it's properly configured. I have no idea how your vagrant stuff and/or your home network is setup, but you usually only need one DNS cache in your main router that's connected to your ISP. If you want to set up virtual machines, and provide DNS service for them, make sure only they see the DNS service you use for that, and that's the only DNS service they see. Or just use good old `/etc/hosts`, and ditch DNS.

Comment: @dirkt I just tried uninstalling the plugin and then nothing was DNS resolving. Then I removed the 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 from my DHCP and DNS configs and now DNS resolution is working again. I am going to see if this fixes it, bark at the landrush developers if it did, and then also try to edit this question into something salvageable and ping you to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you use Google or OpenDNS dns server, rather than from your local ISP/router.

```
sudo gedit /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

add this line

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

Save the file, restart computer and you are edone.

Comment: I tried this with DNS instead of DHCP, but I will go ahead and give this a shot. I have restarted network and DNS services after adding that line and will see what happens.

Comment: restart your PC, use REBOOT not restart service.

Comment: Ok I tried this and I am still having DNS resolution errors.

Comment: I must tell you, because your youtube is set to Canada that doesn't mean you have DNS resolution errors.
Does sites you visit resolve properly?
Can you ping those sites on which you are "encountering errors".
If you can, then dns is working fine and the issue is within something else.

Comment: P.S You can change your Youtube location at the bottom of the page.
Also i recommend clearing cache and cookies from browser and checking your google account settings.

Comment: I cannot access websites or package repos due to DNS resolution errors. I also flushed my DNS cache in Chrome after restarting.

Comment: What errors, can you paste some output.
What happens when you do ping.
When that happen can u ping 8.8.8.8 or google.com
Does your internet work at all

Comment: I can ping 8.8.8.8, but I cannot ping a website with DNS resolution issues.